# App is not supported on some devices on Google Play Unsupported (3446)

Tags: android, permissions, google-play, android-manifest

I uploaded an app on goolge play with minimum sdk14
even galaxy tap is not supported

aapt dump badging

> sdkVersion:'14' targetSdkVersion:'14' uses-permission:
>   name='android.permission.CAMERA' uses-permission:
>   name='android.permission.INTERNET' uses-permission:
>   name='android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO' uses-permission:
>   name='android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS' uses-permission:
>   name='android.permission.WAKE_LOCK' uses-permission:
>   name='android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
>   application-icon-120:'res/drawable-ldpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
>   application-icon-160:'res/drawable/ic_launcher.png'
>   application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
>   application-icon-320:'res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
>   application-icon-480:'res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
>   application-icon-640:'res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
>   application: label='DoctorPol' icon='res/drawable/ic_launcher.png'
>   launchable-activity: name='com.myapp.app.SplashScreen'  label='App'
>   icon= '' feature-group: label=''   uses-feature:
>   name='android.hardware.camera'   uses-feature:
>   name='android.hardware.camera.autofocus'   uses-feature:
>   name='android.hardware.microphone'   uses-implied-feature:
>   name='android.hardware.microphone' reason='requested and
>   roid.permission.RECORD_AUDIO permission'   uses-feature:
>   name='android.hardware.screen.landscape'   uses-implied-feature:
>   name='android.hardware.screen.landscape' reason='one or more
>   activities have specified a landscape orientation'   uses-feature:
>   name='android.hardware.screen.portrait'   uses-implied-feature:
>   name='android.hardware.screen.portrait' reason='one or m ore
>   activities have specified a portrait orientation'   uses-feature:
>   name='android.hardware.touchscreen'   uses-implied-feature:
>   name='android.hardware.touchscreen' reason='default feat ure for all
>   apps' main other-activities supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large'
>   'xlarge' supports-any-density: 'true' locales: '--_--' 'tr' densities:
>   '120' '160' '240' '320' '480' '640' native-code: 'armeabi' 'x86'

Comment: You need to check the permission and remove the unwanted permission from manifest file.

Comment: you can see the permissions I am using they are only normally required permissions, and also i tried to install the apk manually and it is working good on the unSupported devices .!

Comment: analyse the features and technical specification of unsupported devices along with permission.

Comment: No Confliction it's fully supported :(